# Question regarding formatting contents of a cell in a table

Tags: tables

So I have the table below. It's very ugly how e.g. the contents of the second cell in row two is split. I'd prefer the automatic break to only occur between words -- that is, I don't want it to split any of the words/symbol strings. Is there any way to do this? Thanks a lot.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{book} \setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\usepackage{graphicx} \usepackage{gb4e} \usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{setspace} \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} \usepackage{multirow}
\setcounter{part}{-1} \setcounter{subsection}{0}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}   
\begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{ |p{0.18\textwidth}| p{0.18\textwidth}| p{0.18\textwidth} p{0.18\textwidth}|p{0.18\textwidth} |}  \hline  \textbf{S>O} &
    \textbf{A'rau} & \textbf{Northern (Zam)} & \textbf{Intermediate(Ba'ro)} &\textbf{Southern (nGora)}\\ \hline  1(>3) & -isratha $\sim$ -sajana & -iriska:ta & -ira:tha & irijatha\\ \hline   
    \end{tabular}
\end{center}  
\caption{Past counterfactual paradigm}  
\label{pastCFcompare}  
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Not related to your question, but note that you should use `\centering` instead of `\begin{center}...\end{center}`, due spacing issues.

Answer (score 1):

After some corrections, in particular `\\`, not `\` before `\hline`. As far as I understand, the string `sajana` should appear in the next line. If `-` belongs to the string, all may be surrounded by `\mbox`.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{book} 
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4} 
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{gb4e}
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{part}{-1} \setcounter{subsection}{0}

\begin{table} 
\begin{center} 
\begin{tabular}{ |p{0.18\textwidth}| p{0.18\textwidth}| p{0.18\textwidth}| p{0.18\textwidth}|p{0.18\textwidth} |} 
  \hline 
  \textbf{S>O} & \textbf{A'rau} & \textbf{Northern (Zam)} & \textbf{Intermediate (Ba'ro)} &\textbf{Southern (nGora)}\\
  \hline 
  1(>3) & -isratha $\sim$ -sajana & -iriska:ta & -ira:tha & irijatha\\
  \hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\caption{Past counterfactual paradigm}
\label{pastCFcompare} 
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot -- but this is precisely the issue I'm trying to resolve: the dash belongs to the string. How can \mbox solve this?

Comment: Try putting `\mbox{-sajana}`. `\mbox` will but a box around it's argument, boxes cannot be split over lines so it will be all together on one line.